# stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle requires errors

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php, stofdoctrineextensions

My composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
```

and after composer update/install (tried both) i got that kind error

"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.1.0 requires gedmo/doctrine-extensions 2.3.* -> no matching package found"

(picture uploaded). I deleted the stof required and then everything works just fine. Got it in all my projects (~~ 15 totally on storage).

[image: composer errors]

Comment: "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.1.0 requires gedmo/doctrine-extensions 2.3.* -> no matching package found"

or:
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle dev-master requires gedmo/doctrine-extensions dev-master -> no matching package found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove 
 "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",

stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle has it in its dependencies https://packagist.org/packages/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle

and will install latest v2.3.12 https://packagist.org/packages/gedmo/doctrine-extensions satisfied by dependency: gedmo/doctrine-extensions: ~2.3.1

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
```